# Can't get a checkbox value inside a gridviewrow controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i programatically populate a gridview with checkbox like this

```
Dim checkbox As New CheckBox()
checkbox.Checked = True
checkbox.ID = String.Format("chkChecked{0}", i)
MyRow.Cells(i).Controls.Add(checkbox)
```

later on i tried to access them with this

```
Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast( Row.FindControl(String.Format("chkChecked{0}", i)),CheckBox)
```

over the row but it does'nt work, any idea of what is going on? thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code to access CheckBox control inside `CellContentClick` or `CellClick` events of the `DataGridView` :

```
Dim CheckBox As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = CType(grdDataGridView.CurrentCell, DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
```

If you want you can replace `grdDataGridView.CurrentCell` with `grdDataGridView(columnIndex,rowIndex)`.

At the end I use `EditedFormattedValue` to check the value of the `CheckBox`.

```
If (CheckBox.EditedFormattedValue) Then
    ....
End If
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Regrads,
Boris

Comment: Hi thanks for the help Boris, but i ended up populating my gridview columns with checkboxfield programatically and that did the trick, but thanks for help good sir, cheers